# Google wont apply adsense policies for session based websites and Ajax loaded sites?

Tags: seo, google-search, google-adsense, googlebot, adult-content

I have seen so many websites (Mostly User generated content - Getting contents from Third party API's) still displaying Adult like contents (with images) but still they are running well with Google Adsense without any issues.

Below is url that displays the Adult contents (you can view only if you logged into the Instagram.)

http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/635186136754514912_477290089

I wont say this is a bad or Adult site. Because of user generated content, the page contains Adult content (Even you can see the F..k word too). But they are displaying Google ads.

My Questions here is,

If a website main content loaded via Ajax (but not the Advertisement, Header and Footer). So Google adsense or Google can not able to find violation in the page. Is this correct?

If a website displays main content only by visitor login (but not the Advertisement, Header and Footer), So Google crawler can not able to find violation in the page.

Am i right in the above points?

Answer (score 2):

> If a website main content loaded via Ajax (but not the Advertisement,
>   Header and Footer). So Google adsense or Google can not able to find
>   violation in the page. Is this correct?

It used to be, but not anymore. Google bots can now crawl ajax and javascript content.

> If a website displays main content only by visitor login (but not the Advertisement, Header and Footer), So Google crawler can not able to find violation in the page.

Google bots cannot crawl login only pages. So any policy violation existing there won't be detected by Google bots unless you have an adsense employee as a registered user of your website. However, Google recommends handing adsense crawler access to login only pages, because that way the crawler can decide what might be the best ads for those pages. However, it is a choice the webmaster will have to make. If he decides against it, then there is nothing to worry about.

Disclaimer : This answer is based on the assumption that Google finds adsense policy violations solely on the basis of what the crawler finds. If Google uses any other method (such as taking a screenshot of the page while a click is made on the ad ;)) then there is every chance that the violation will be found. But the exact mechanisms of policy violation detection remains unknown to most people (just like their  search algorithm).

Update: There are also times when Google can determine some policy violations based on the feedback the users provide. In that case, even policy violations in login only pages can also be seen by Google.